# Error when using SetAngle

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is the error I get:

T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::physics::Joint]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

Can anybody tell me what it means?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/797/error-when-using-setangle/) by [jarevalo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/139/jarevalo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found out... Never mind.

I was using the same pointer name for two different joints without realizing.

---

Originally posted by [jarevalo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/139/jarevalo/) with karma: 33 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0